# Relationship $f(x)$ and $\max(f(x))$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, inequality, real-numbers

If $f(x),g(x)$ are functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$  and we define $$X=\max\left[0,\max(-f(x))\right]$$ and $$Y=\max\left[0,\max(-g(x))\right]$$

I need to know if the following inequality is true: $\exists C\geq 0$
 $$\left|X-Y\right|\leq C\left|\max (-f(x))-\max (-g(x))\right|\leq C\max  \left|f(x)-g(x)\right|$$

Comment: The minus in front of $f$ and $g$ are inessential.

Comment: that is true use the algebraic definition of max

Comment: what does the max (-f) mean by the way

Comment: The inequality $\left|\max (f(x))-\max (g(x))\right|\leq \max  \left|f(x)-g(x)\right|$ does not hold in general !

Comment: you can see     https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2417548/true-or-false-left-max-limits-x-in-dfx-max-limits-x-in-dgx-right?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

we have $$\max\{f(x),g(x)\}=\dfrac{1}{2}[f(x)+g(x)+|f(x)-g(x)|]$$
Therefore
$$X=\max\{0,\max(-f(x))\}=\dfrac{1}{2}[\max(-f(x))+|\max(-f(x))|]$$
 and 
$$Y=\max\{0,\max(-g(x))\}=\dfrac{1}{2}[\max(-g(x))+|\max(-g(x))|]$$

then, we get
\begin{equation}
\left|X-Y\right|=\left|\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\max (-f(x))+|\max (-f(x))|\right]-\dfrac{1}{2}\left[\max (-g(x))-|\max (-g(x))|\right]\right|\\
\leq \dfrac{1}{2}\left|\max (-f(x))-\max (-g(x))|+\dfrac{1}{2}||\max (-f(x))|-|\max (-g(x))|\right|\\
\end{equation}

Since  $||a|-|b||\leq |a-b| ,|\max(x)-\max(y)|\leq \max|x-y|$, we get

therefore
\begin{equation}
\left|X-Y\right|\leq \left|\max(-f(x))-\max (-g(x))\right|\leq \max\left|f(x)-g(x)\right|
\end{equation}

Comment: Do the  above proof is true or not?

Comment: Where is $C$ gone ?

Comment: what happen if C=1

Comment: Sorry, but this deosn't answer my question.

Comment: I think that c dont give any sense, don't it?

Comment: $C$ appears in the question, there is no reason to throw it away.

Answer (score 0):

This question does not really make sense if $C$ is arbitrary. The equality is

$$|f(x)-g(x)|\ge\frac{|X-Y|}C$$ and the RHS can be made arbitrarily small.

If $X=Y$, the inequality is always fulfilled.

If $X\ge Y$, it can always be fulfilled, except where $f(x)=g(x)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, the inequality is $$\left|X-Y\right|\leq C\left|\max (f(x))-\max (g(x))\right|$$

Comment: thank you for your answer

Answer (score 0):

Due to the $\min/\max$ clauses, you don't need to worry about the particular function values. The inequalities are just between four numbers.

Let $f_M:=\max(f(x))$ and $f_m:=\min(f(x))$ and similarly for $g$.

Then, by definition

$$f_m\le f_M,\\g_m\le g_M,$$

and we are given that
$$X=\max(0,-f_m),\\Y=\max(0,-g_m).$$

and we are asked to prove

$$|X-Y|\le C|f_M-g_M|.$$

---

For arbitray $C$ we can always achieve that, except when $X\ne Y\land f_M= g_M$.

Comment: thank you for your answer